# Preserve test data even after completion of unit test (not just database)

Tags: python, django, database

I want to use my test database with data in it which was created when testcase ran, how can i do it?

I tried running normal django test which inherits `TestCase` and put a break point after test data is been generated. Now if I login to the test_db (which django creates) in different terminal tab through postgres command and query it, no data is shown! can someone explain why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

[`TestCase`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/testing/tools/#testcase) wraps tests in an atomic block and rolls back the transaction so that no changes are saved to the database.

If you want changes to be saved, you could use [`SimpleTestCase`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/testing/tools/#simpletestcase), and set `databases = __all__` (Django 2.2+), or `allow_database_queries = True` (earlier versions of Django).